# redirect wp-admin/install.php

Tags: redirect

My website redirects to wp-admin/install.php. The install.php page is completely blank. This came on all of a sudden. And sometime website working fine.

Any ideas on why it could be redirecting to that? How to resolve it?

Thanks,
Nilam

Comment: you should ask for help from your hosting. sounds like it is impossible to read the wp-config.php file, the random behaviour hints to something additional going on.

Answer (score 1):

If you say the issue is **intermittent** and when the site does not work it redirects you to wp-admin/install.php it is very likely that you are hitting the maximum number of database connections set by your hosting provider. Once you hit the limit the site won’t be able to connect to the database and will redirect you to the install page, after one hour when the count resets the site will work again until the limit is reached and so on.

You might be reaching the maximum number of database connections for many reasons, but these are the most likely:

- Your site gets a lot of traffic, or at least picks with lots of traffic
- You are experiencing a small ddos attack
- Your themes or one of your plugins has a bug that is causing an excessive number of database connections.

If you don´t think traffic is the issue then try deactivating your plugins see if that fixes it, if it does then activate them one by one until you find the one causing the issue and replace for an alternative one.

If you find that plugins are not the issue either then definitely contact your hosting provider explaining the situation.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

> You could try checking your wp-config.php file to see that the
>   database settings are correct and also that the **$table_prefix** setting
>   matches the table prefixes in your database.

```
You can check the database name and prefixes in phpMyAdmin.
```